# Do other countries than Germany have traffic laws that regard a group of civil vehicles as one single vehicle?

Tags: germany, traffic, france

I'm mostly interested in the situation in France, but this might be interesting for other countries as well, especially in the context of the current rise of bicycle usage:

Germany has § 27 in its traffic law (StVO), permitting huge groups of cyclists to go through traffic as one single vehicle, even crossing red traffic lights as long as the vehicles at the front passed at green.

Do similar laws (for civil use) exist in France or other countries?

A first look at the French code de la route revealed nothing, and Wikipedia has no translations listed for the German article.

- German law: https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stvo_2013/__27.html
- Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verband_(Stra%C3%9Fenverkehr)#Radfahrer

Answer (score 6):

Spain also considers a group of cyclists as a single vehicle in some circumstances.

[This guide from the Dirección General de Tráfico](http://www.dgt.es/PEVI/eduvial/guias-didacticas-recursos/Guia-del-ciclista-marcadores.pdf) shows, at page 10, about right of way:

> También se tiene prioridad de paso cuando el vehículo de motor vaya a girar, a la derecha o a la izquierda, para entrar en otra vía y el ciclista  esté  próximo  o  cuando  circulando  en  grupo  el  primero  haya iniciado el cruce o haya entrado en una glorieta.

or

> [The cyclist] also has right of way [with respect to a motor vehicle] when the motor vehicle is going to turn, right or left, to enter another road and the cyclist is nearby, or when cycling in a group the first has started the crossing or has entered the roundabout.

I can see no other differences related to travelling in group; in particular the only references to red lights and pedestrian crossings is that cyclists must stop at them, without mentioning any difference if part of the group has already passed.

Comment: Are there limitations on the size or shape of a group of cyclists (or am I allowed to travel through Spain in a group of 200 cyclists)?

Comment: By that, I mean is what you said true "up to a point?" Like, does a 30-km-long caravan of cyclists count as a "group?"